# Looking for ancient gems

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2, legacy

Does anyone have, or know where I can find, a copy of any of these old gems? They seem to have been taken offline, and I need them to work on a legacy project.

- `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0.9250`
- `log4r-1.0.5`
- `RMagick-win32-1.9.2`
- `win32-sapi-0.1.3`

Comment: Look, I know this isn't the sort of thing that you're supposed to ask on Stack Overflow, but I'm reaching the end of my chain here...

Comment: if its not there in the releases tab of github. I think your best bet would be to email its developer ;)